# Incremental charset with no duplicate adjacent letter

Tags: password-cracking, dictionary

I'm using John the Ripper and the following charset in the creation of a word list:

```
[Incremental:Upper8]
File = $JOHN/upper.chr
MinLen = 8
MaxLen = 8
CharCount = 36
```

The command:

```
john –stdout –incremental=Upper8  > wordlist.txt
```

---

I want to create a wordlist using uppercase letters only, of strings only 8 characters long, but never should any adjacent letter be duplicated.

Example:

- ABC*BBAAA* - this should not happen as there are 3 adjacent A's and 2 adjacent B's
- ABCBABAB - this is fine as there are no duplicate adjacent letters

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: I'm betting there's some regexp you could pipe through `grep` or `perl` to do filter out the ones you don't want. https://unix.stackexchange.com is a good place to get help for that.

Comment: This is ultimately a coding/scripting question rather than a security question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get it working with crunch. This will be over 1 TB....

```
./crunch 8 8 -f charset.ls ualpha -d 1@ -o wordlist.txt
```

- **8 8** = Set the minimum and maximum length both to 8
- **-f charset.ls ualpha** = Set a character set of uppercase alphabet
- **-d 1@** -  Will print all combinations with 1 or less adjacent uppercase duplicate.
- **-o** = the output of the file.

Comment: `-d 1@` would be for LOWERCASE, use `-d 1,` for UPPERCASE

Answer (score -1):

Here is a python script: https://github.com/skriachko/scrunch

Run it with option --no-rep and it will exclude character duplicates. For example:

```
python scrunch.pyc --no-rep 3 3 AB12
```

will give you the following combinations:

```
12A
12B
1A2
1AB
1B2
1BA
21A
21B
2A1
2AB
2B1
2BA
A12
A1B
A21
A2B
AB1
AB2
B12
B1A
B21
B2A
BA1
BA2
```

You can also use option --no-digit-start to remove combinations starting from digit